# Can I automate Nero's mp3 encoding?

Tags: user-interface, encoding, automation, mp3, autoit

I'd like to automate Nero's mp3 encoding so that I could perhaps just drag and drop a wav file and get it as an mp3 in 256 kbps instead of going thru all the menus each time I publish a new loop. Can you ihnt me how to do it with autoIT if it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perhaps use something that has a command line interface and hence would allow easy scripting. [Lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) is a good example. Look [here](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/292074-How-do-I-use-Lame-command-line) for some examples of using it from command line. Not sure, but perhaps vlc can also be used for the job.

Comment: +1: Command line is always better than automating user interfaces. Nero also has a command line interface (see [here](http://ftp6.nero.com/user_guides/utilities/nerocmd/NeroCMDUser.pdf))

Comment: On Linux, I recently used ffmpeg as well: `ffmpeg -i input_file -vn -ab 256k file.mp3` will do the job. This can be easily scripted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [LAME](http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/USAGE) and a batch script in your Windows' SendTo folder:

`lame -h --abr 256 "%~1" "%~dpn1.mp3"`